# Increment a string value

Tags: c#, .net, variables

How can I increment a string value? For example:

```
string RECONCILIATION_COUNT;
if (thing happens) {
    RECONCILIATION_COUNT++;
}
```

This is normally wont work since it is not possible to increment a string variable in the same way used for int values.

`RECONCILIATION_COUNT` is always a number from 0-5.

I chose to declare it as a string since I am getting this value from database and i am not finding a way how to get an int value from sql.

```
RECONCILIATION_COUNT = Rows["RECONCILIATION_COUNT"].toString();
```

This is what I am using for the moment.

Comment: `RECONCILIATION_COUNT = (int.Parse(RECONCILIATION_COUNT) + 1).ToString();`

Comment: So it sounds you would rather know how to parse the db value to `int` than to keep it as string and try to implement `int` operations on that string? Try  `Convert.ToInt32(Rows["RECONCILIATION_COUNT"]);` To use a bad type design just because you don't know how to parse is a bad idea.

Comment: Firstly don't store numeric values as strings in a db, secondly, don't name your variables in caps, my OCD kicks off. and thirdly, see the first point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite weird to have a *count* as a `String`: `int` is by far much natural choice. Technically, you can put it as

```
if (thing happens)
  RECONCILIATION_COUNT = (int.Parse(RECONCILIATION_COUNT) + 1).ToString();
```

a better implementation is to use `int`:

```
int RECONCILIATION_COUNT;

...

if (thing happens)
  RECONCILIATION_COUNT++;

...

RECONCILIATION_COUNT = Convert.ToInt32(Rows["RECONCILIATION_COUNT"]);
```

Comment: USing  RECONCILIATION_COUNT = Convert.ToInt32(Rows["RECONCILIATION_COUNT"]); is giving me this kind of error  "Column 'RECONCILIATION COUNT' does not belong to table "  when in fact the column does exist in the table

Comment: Please, check exact column name.

Comment: i copy- paste the column name from the table everywhere in my code so i don't think is a misspelling thing. This is the query i use to firstly select query = " SELECT ID, REF_NO, CARD_DEBIT_OR_CREDIT";
                query += " FROM " + clsUtility.GetMasterTable() + " ";
                query += " WHERE FLOW_STATUS_IS_CURRENT = 1 ";
                query += " AND RECONCILIATION_STATUS = 0";
                query += " AND RECONCILIATION_COUNT < 5";
                query += " AND (FLOW_STATUS = 'DeliverToCustomer' ";
                query += " AND ACTIVATION_FAILURE = 'Fail') ";

Comment: I don't see any RECONCILIATION_COUNT in the SELECT. It seems you should add the field into SELECT

Answer (score 2):

If you'd rather get your value as a string from the database, you can then parse it to an "int" later on :

Use the [Int32.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx) method :

```
 int number = Int32.Parse(RECONCILIATION_COUNT);
```

Or the [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) method :

```
     int number;

     bool result = Int32.TryParse(RECONCILIATION_COUNT, out number);
     if (result)
     {
        // do your increment     
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RECONCILIATION_COUNT = "" + (int32.Parse(RECONCILIATION_COUNT) + 1);
```

But if the variable is always a number, I'd rather declare RECONCILIATION_COUNT as int and parse the text to a number when uploading it from database.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach here is a bit weird. You're creating a tight coupling between data types in SQL and your code and by doing this you're accumulating technical debt (workarounds) just because of DB constraints.

What i'd recommend you do is that in your repository you do the conversion from string to int and backwards (when you want to write that value in the DB).

All the answers about using the int.parse (or the like) are valid, but think about it a bit in more detail what happens if you do something like:

```
reconciliation_count = int.parse(reconciliation_count)++.ToString();
```

Break it down:
- int.parse - allocates memory for a new variable which you increment
- ToString - allocates memory for a NEW string which gets reasigned to your variable

There's a lot of memory going up and down and you're relying on the GC to clear up everything for you, and don't forget that strings are immutable.

However, if you follow my approach you can just assign one int variable ONCE and do whatever you want with it and then when you save it in the DB job is done.

Hope this helps.